# insert using select distinct

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Let's say, I have 2 tables t1 and t2.

```
create table t1 
{
id int not null,
col1 int null,
col2 int null,
col3 int null
}

create table t2
{
id uniqueidentifier not null,
col1 int null,
col2 int null,
col3 int null
}
```

I want to insert the below resultset into table t2.

```
select distinct col1, col2, col3 from t1
```

How can I achieve this using a query? I tried below statement but I know it's syntactically wrong.

```
insert into t2
select newid(), distinct col1, col2, col3 from t1
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
insert into t2
select newid(),a.*
from
(Select distinct col1, col2, col3 from t1) a
```

Answer (score 2):

You can omit `uniqueidentifier` field if it's auto generated.

```sql
INSERT INTO t2 (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2, col3 FROM t1
```

More on that [Using uniqueidentifier Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190215%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: that is only if it is auto generated, if it is plainly int or null, ofc not

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
INSERT INTO t2
SELECT NEWID(), col1, col2, col3 
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2, col3 
    FROM t1
)DT
```